# Firebase Invalid key: . Keys must not contain '/', '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'

Tags: android, firebase

Why is this error happening? In the debug mode there's no special characters in the key, no '.', only the '/' necessary for the path. It was working well, I just wiped my database and then I run again with the error in the title. My code:

DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

```
String animalUid = animal.getUid();

if (animalUid == null) {
    animalUid = databaseReference.push().getKey();
}

Map<String, Object> animalData = new HashMap();


if(animal.getFavorites()!=null) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, Boolean> entry : animal.getFavorites().entrySet()) {
        animalData.put("users-favorites-animals/" + entry.getKey() + "/" + animalUid, animal);
    }
}

animalData.put("users-animals/" + animal.getOwnerUid() + "/" + animalUid, animal);
animalData.put("animals/" + animalUid, animal);

databaseReference.updateChildren(animalData).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
        listener.onSaveAnimalSucess(animal);
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

        if (e instanceof FirebaseException) {
            listener.onSaveAnimalError("");
            return;
        }

        listener.onConnectionError();
    }
});
```

Here how the animalData keys comes before updateChildren:

"animals/-Kcd_8Tif5EPYUhsceeH"

"users-animals/LoQ9Bkjs2yVC95nFGyo1ft4cqdB2/-Kcd_8Tif5EPYUhsceeH"

Even my old code without the multi-data updates is not working, with the same error. I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: Key should not contain /, your key does. What is not clear here?

Comment: this is not a key, this is a deep path that firebase supports, but it keeps calling key as an old firebase version. I don't know why https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/09/introducing-multi-location-updates-and_86.html

Comment: You are reading a blog from an old version of firebase (Android (2.4.0)). Where the latest is `10.0.x`... Check the latest API

Comment: This is Multi-path updates ,I don't think they removed this function from Firebase. Look the date of this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i1n9Kw3AORw

Comment: Can you please tell us the values of `animalUid`, and `animal.getOwnerUid()`?

Comment: You are right, `/` is valid as part of path. Just checked it works fine on my side... so something else must be wrong on yours and we don't have full picture. What your actual composed key looks like?

Comment: I just added how the keys shows in the OP.

Comment: Please post the stack trace for the exception.

Comment: https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Realtime%20Database/17007

could be this the problem?

Answer (score 1):

not sure if that will help you, but i am using some components which temper with my personal objects :D (for example, primeng autoselect box adds something like '_$visited' to my data). 
In case someone is facing the same issue and does not really need those kind of keys in your objects you might consider calling the following function. (you need to have lodash for it)

```
private makeObjectGreatAgain(object: any) {
// removing undefined values from any arrays!
// and some variables which are added by different components
// firebase not allowed keys: ".", "#", "$", "/", "[", or "]"
object = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object), (key, val) => {
  if (!_.includes(key, '.') && !_.includes(key, '#') && !_.includes(key, '$') &&
    !_.includes(key, '/') && !_.includes(key, '[') && !_.includes(key, ']')) {
    return val;
  } else {
    console.log('removing invalid key: ' + key + ' val: ' + val);
  }
});
return object;
}
```